# How do I convert a document to a preview image?

Tags: 7, views, media, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert first page of a pdf as its thumbnail?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/how-can-i-convert-first-page-of-a-pdf-as-its-thumbnail)

I have a file field which allow users to upload document types like pdf, doc and txt. Now I want to convert first page of each document to a Thumbnail. I want this action either for CCK display and Views Field.
I already found some solution ( [1](http://drupal.org/node/641372) , [2](http://drupal.org/node/460132) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)) but the two first are for Drupal 6 and the third one is just a php solution which I don't know how to make it work in my drupal7 system?
Now what should I do to make these type of thumbnails in Drupal7?

Comment: sure, but do you have any idea to use that php code which linked in that answer in drupal?!:(

Comment: no, sorry. just helping to moderate the question. :)